# Differential Equations: Solving a second order ODE with DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following equation

```
h''[η] + (2 a'/a) h'[η] + (k)^2 h[η] == 0
2 a'/a = 1.3551
```

with boundary conditions

```
h[0] == 1, h'[0] == 0
```

where `k` is some constant factor. I have to plot `h[η]` @ `η = c` versus `k η` @ `η = c`. So far this is what I have done:

```
sol = DSolve[{h''[η] + (2 a'/a) h'[η] + (k)^2 h[η] == 0, h[0] == 1, h'[0] == 0},
            h[η], η] /. η -> 1.48* 0.0195

Plot[h[0.02886`] /. sol, {k, 0, 1000}]
```

As a note: I was expected to plot vs `k η` but since *Mathematica* is refusing to do so I plotted vs `k` only. 
The result looks like this

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However the solution should be damped with 3 oscillations only as shown below:[image: Expected plotsshown by dotted lines]

Comment: Can you add the definition of `a` ?

Comment: Please, visit the help centre to read about the proper code formatting practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation describes the damped harmonic oscillator. The general form is 
   $ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + 2\zeta\omega_0\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \omega_0^{\,2} x = 0$, where $\omega_0$ is a frequency (note that this is like `k` in your case) and $\zeta$ is a damping parameter.
In your textbook the author chose to change variables form $\eta$ to $v=\eta k$ which changes your equation into
`g''[v] + a g'[v] + g[v] == 0,`
where `a=(2 a'/a)/k` and `v=kη`.

We can easily solve this

```
sol = DSolve[{g''[v] + a g'[v] + g[v] == 0, g[0] == 1, g'[0] == 0}, g,
     v] // FullSimplify;
exp1[η_, k_, par_] := Module[{aa = par/k},
  fun[a_] = g /. sol[[1]];
  Return[fun[aa][k η]]
  ]
```

where `par=1.3551`.
When we inspect the solution for the parameters you mentioned

```
exp[0.02886, k, 1.3551] // FullSimplify
```

one can clearly see that there is no exponential decay as one would expect (the result is proportional to `E^(-0.01443 Sqrt[-4 + 1.836296/k^2] k)`). The argument of exponential function is complex for `k>0.678`.

**My guess is that there might be a mistake in the differential equation that you have.**
For instance, if we define

```
exp2[η_, k_, par_] := Module[{aa = par},
      fun[a_] = g /. sol[[1]];
      Return[fun[aa][k η]]
      ]
(*this is effectively a solution of h''[η] + (2 a'/a) k h'[η] + (k)^2 h[η] == 0*)
```

we'll get the expected behavior. Here's a comparison.

```
list1 = Map[{0.02886 #, exp1[0.02886, #, 1.3551]} &, Range[0.1, 400]];
list2 = Map[{0.02886 #, exp2[0.02886, #, 1.3551]} &, Range[0.1, 400]];

{list1, list2} // 
 ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"η k", "h"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"exp1", "exp2"}, {0.87, 0.85}]] &
```

[image]
Maybe it's hard to notice the oscillations but this is due to value of $\zeta$ (for  $\zeta<1$ they would be much more pronounced).

Comment: Note that my picture differs from yours as I don't have a logscale for $\eta k$.

Comment: Indeed .. that was wonderful approach. thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it works.